# Authentication of ifttt

Tags: ifttt

I want to do my own service on `ifttt` and I need `oauth2` certification.
First step based on `oauth2` authentication: get code
This is the value of code in my program:

[image]

This is the value he demands to return

[image]

But it prompts that I have failed to connect.
How to to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code here in your question, not as a screenshot. Others are currently unable to copy it and so nobody is able to reproduce your problem. Please also post your error messages (including the stacktrace) and add the tag of your programming language (it's Java I think). Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first then read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.I used it before:http://localhost:8080,And then I changed it 
 htts://

The problem has been solved